Как перевести значение из базы в DateTime?
не могу понять в каком формате хранится время в таблице базы данных. Тип данных в таблице - bigint. Время в таблицу записывается с интервалом в один час. Одно из значений времени равно 637976910630000000. Предположил что время пишется в базу в Unix формате, но это очень огромное число, пробовал делать различные преобразования, но вменяемого результата не получил, получается очень большая дата. База данных MS SQL. В то же время есть софтина, которая тоже запрашивает данные из этой таблицы и рисует графики, там время выводится корректно. В запрос этой программы залезть возможности нет. Помогите преобразовать это значение в нормальный формат даты.

Есть на англоязычном варианте стака.
select dateadd(s, convert(bigint, 1283174502729) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00')).
Ищите по "Convert bigint to datetime"

Скорее такая цифра получена из даты с точностью до 100 наносекунд.
Допустим, вот такой пример:
DECLARE @num [bigint] = 637976910639900123;

Для парсинга даты я бы разбил это значение на несколько сегментов: дни для подсчета даты, секунды для подсчета времени и наносекунды чтобы не терять точность.
Начало даты не unixtimestamp. Значение слишком велико для этого. Скорее это 1 января 0001 года.
Находим делители дат:
DECLARE @nanoSecPrecise [bigint] = 100;

DECLARE @dayHours [bigint] = 24;
DECLARE @hourMinutes [bigint] = 60;
DECLARE @minuteSeconds [bigint] = 60;
DECLARE @secondMilliseconds [bigint] = 1000;
DECLARE @millisecondsMicroseconds [bigint] = 1000;
DECLARE @microsecondsNanoseconds [bigint] = 1000 / @nanoSecPrecise;

DECLARE @daySeparator [bigint] = @dayHours * @hourMinutes * @minuteSeconds * @secondMilliseconds * @millisecondsMicroseconds * @microsecondsNanoseconds;
DECLARE @secondsSeparator [bigint] = @secondMilliseconds * @millisecondsMicroseconds * @microsecondsNanoseconds;

И находим дату:
DECLARE @days [bigint] = @num / @daySeparator;
DECLARE @time [bigint] = (@num % @daySeparator) / @secondsSeparator;
DECLARE @nanoseconds [bigint] =  ((@num % @daySeparator) % @secondsSeparator) * @nanoSecPrecise;

DECLARE @startDate [datetime2] = CONVERT([datetime2], '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000', 121);
DECLARE @dayAdds [datetime2] = DATEADD([DAY], @days, @startDate);
DECLARE @timeAdds [datetime2] = DATEADD([SECOND], @time, @dayAdds);
DECLARE @dt2Precision [datetime2] = DATEADD([NANOSECOND], @nanoseconds, @timeAdds);


Результат можно проверить:
SELECT
  @daySeparator AS [@daySeparator],
  @secondsSeparator AS [@secondsSeparator],
  @days AS [@days],
  @time AS [@time],
  @nanoseconds AS [@nanoseconds],
  @startDate AS [@startDate],
  @dayAdds AS [@dayAdds],
  @timeAdds AS [@timeAdds],
  @dt2Precision AS [@dt2Precision]

Вывод:



@daySeparator
@secondsSeparator
@days
@time
@nanoseconds
@startDate
@dayAdds
@timeAdds
@dt2Precision




864000000000
10000000
738399
17463
990012300
0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
2022-09-02 00:00:00.0000000
2022-09-02 04:51:03.0000000
2022-09-02 04:51:03.9900123




Странная начальная дата. Нигде вроде бы нет такой что бы с 0001-01-01. unix time считает с 1970г

Тоже считаю что странно. Если это было unix time то скорее начинался бы со значения ~16-17 и имел бы до 19 символов при точности до наносекунд. А тут 18 символов и предположил, что использовался тип datetime2, которая начинается с 0001-01-01.

Я совсем не понимаю в SQLServer, сам использую postgresql, однако, стало интересно, что это за дата и я провел ряд экспериментов. Конечно, сильно бы помогло с поиском верного ответа, если бы автор хотя бы приблизительно назвал реальные даты событий, тогда было бы с чем сопоставлять. Если предположить, что это наносекунды в UNIXtime, то деление даты на 10^9 дает вполне адекватный результат, но, повторю, без понимания, что это за события и когда они в реальности произошли, не понятно, насколько всеже результат  адекватен.
Эксперимент на питоне:
from datetime import datetime

datetime_start = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(637976910630000000 / 1_000_000_000))

print(datetime_start)

Дает результат:
1990-03-21 02:48:30.630000

Решение для SQLServer
Для конвертации этого числа в дату в SQLServer нашел решение через сложение секунд со стартовой датой:
Select
    dateadd(S, [unixtime], '1970-01-01')
From [Table]

Взято отсюда, сам не пробовал.
